# UWP Xbox One WiFi capability is always "DeniedBySystem"

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi, xbox-one

Does anyone has any experience with the wiFiControl Device Capability on Xbox One? I am working on an app and I need access to WiFiAdapter.

Whenever I deploy the app on my Xbox One and request access to the adapter using the following way:

```
var result = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
```

The result I get is always `WiFiAccessStatus.DeniedBySystem`

I have added the necessary device capability in the app manifest:

`<DeviceCapability Name="wiFiControl" />`

Also, in the [UWP features that aren't yet supported on Xbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt693377) is written that WiFi Direct is not supported, but nothing else related.

Does any one have any hints that might help get access to the wifi adapter?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for report, I'm investigating this issue and will come back soon

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT , sorry to bother, do you have any updates?

Comment: Have not yet, I will inform someone on this